# Guardar datos en mysql usando nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs, web

Estoy intentando guardar los datos en una base de datos (MySQL), pero a la hora de guardar, se guardan pero cuando tú le vuelves a dar en recargar o entras nuevamente a perfil, se vuelve a crear el usuario en la base de datos y eso no es lo que quiero, lo que quiero es que se quede ese usuario.

Aquí muestro el code:

```js
router.get("/", auth, async function(req, res) {
  req.getConnection(async (err, conn, filas) => {
    conn.query(`SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id_user = '${req.user.id}'`);
    
    if (err) return console.error(err.message);
    if (!filas) {
          conn.query(`INSERT INTO usuarios (username, id_user, discriminator, avatar) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)`, [req.user.username, req.user.id, req.user.discriminator, req.user.avatar]);
          console.log('USUARIO NUEVO: '+ req.user.username);
          
        } else {
          console.log('YA ESTA REGISTRADO: '+ req.user.username);
        }
        
        const DatoUsers =
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    conn.query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE username = ?", req.user.username, async (err, filas) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }
      resolve(filas)

    });
  });
  
  let UserData = await DatoUsers.then(data => {
    return data;
  })
  
  res.render("perfil/index.ejs", {
      login: req.isAuthenticated() ? "si" : "no",
      status: req.isAuthenticated() ? "PERFIL" : "LOGIN",
      loginp: (req.isAuthenticated() ? true : false),
      user: UserData
    });
  });
})

module.exports = router;
```

Index.js
Los módulos, los quite para que no sea tan largo.

Este es el archivo principal de mi proyecto donde tengo las rutas, la base de dato y otras cosas más
.................................................

```js
/* --== BASE DE DATOS CONEXION ==-- */
app.use(myConnection(mysql, {
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'fomundi',
  password: '98092410',
  port: 3306,
  database: 'portalfomundi'
}, 'single'));
app.use(bodyparser.json())
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

//Web;
app.use(express.static("../public"));
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user);
});
passport.deserializeUser((obj, done) => {
  done(null, obj);
});
let scope = ["identify"];
passport.use(
  new Strategy(
    {
      clientID: client.config.CLI_ID,
      clientSecret: client.config.CLI_SECRET,
      callbackURL: `${client.config.URL}/login`,
      scope: scope
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
      process.nextTick(function() {
        return done(null, profile);
      });
    }
  )
);
app
  .use(bodyparser.json())
  .use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
  .engine("html", require("ejs").renderFile)
  .use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/public")))
  .set("view engine", "ejs")
  .set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"))
  .set("port", process.env.PORT || 3000)
  .use(
    session({
      secret: "mysatabot",
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: false
    })
  )
  .use(passport.initialize())
  .use(passport.session())
  .use(function(req, res, next) {
    req.client = client;
    next();
  });
// Quite las rutas para que no sea tan largo
});
```

Comment: No se entiende mucho tu manera de trabajar, imagino que estas usando el driver de mysql en un middleware pero mas allá de eso por que tienes un parametro conn y luego lo pides de nuevo en getConnection?

Comment: Ahora, la query es la que recibe el parametro error, a de mas recibe un callback, donde estas evaluado la query y de donde sale el mismo getConnection?, que imagino que deberia ser una conexión "middlewarizada" pero aun asi en la [documentación](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) de mysql indica que los parametros err, results y fields los recibe la query y no la conection, checa eso plis.

Comment: Lo que quiero decir es que el primer conn.query(foo..) no esta yendo a ningun lado, porque no estas pasandole un callback, y estas obteniendo filas de una funcion que seguramente no tiene un parametro filas, por eso da siempre undefined y siempre se inserta el usuario.

Comment: No te hago la respuesta porque el codigo igual esta muy incompleto, pero estoy casi seguro de que es eso, si actualizas tu codigo con mas información como por ejemplo tu index.js te hago la respuesta, sobre todo estaria bueno saber de donde viene getConnection, saludos.

Comment: Publicación Actualizada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basándome en mi comentario, el problema parece ser que esta mal la manera en que estas implementando la conexión y la query de mysql, para mostarte como podrías solucionar tu problema te haré un ejemplo mínimo de como deberías implementar mysql de la manera en que tu lo requieres.

**index.js**

```javascript
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mysql  = require('mysql');
const mainRouter = require('./myRouter.js')
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'me',
  password: 'secret',
  database: 'my_db'
});

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    req.getConnection = connection;
    next();
});
app.use("/", mainRouter)
```

**myRouter.js**

```javascript
const { router } = require('express')

router.get("/", auth, async function(req, res) {
  
  let conn = req.getConnection;
  conn.connect();
    
  conn.query(`SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id_user = ${req.user.id}`, async (err, filas) => {

    if (err) return console.error(err.message);
    if (!filas) {
          conn.query(`INSERT INTO usuarios (username, id_user, discriminator, avatar) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)`, [req.user.username, req.user.id, req.user.discriminator, req.user.avatar]);
          console.log('USUARIO NUEVO: '+ req.user.username);
          
        } else {
          console.log('YA ESTA REGISTRADO: '+ req.user.username);
        }
        
        const DatoUsers =
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    conn.query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE username = ?", req.user.username, async (err, filas) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }
      resolve(filas)

    });
  });
  
  let UserData = await DatoUsers.then(data => {
    return data;
  })
  
  res.render("perfil/index.ejs", {
      login: req.isAuthenticated() ? "si" : "no",
      status: req.isAuthenticated() ? "PERFIL" : "LOGIN",
      loginp: (req.isAuthenticated() ? true : false),
      user: UserData
    });
  });
})

module.exports = router;
```

El problema esta que al obtener la conexión, estas tratándolo como si fuera la query, espero que sea de ayuda, un saludo.